# Oracle SQL - Trigger inserting into table passing null value from sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have two table, **TABLE_A** and **TABLE_B**. When something gets inserted into **TABLE_A** there is a trigger that also inserts the data into **TABLE_B**. **TABLE_A** has an ID column which is populated using a sequence. This id then is also inserted into **TABLE_B**. This is the whole DDL for this:

```
CREATE TABLE  "TABLE_A" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN1" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN2" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
   )
/

CREATE TABLE  "TABLE_B" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN1" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COLUMN2" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
   )

/   

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "AID_PK" ON  "TABLE_A" ("ID")
/

ALTER TABLE  "TABLE_A" ADD CONSTRAINT "AID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  "AID_PK"  ENABLE
/


create or replace TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TABLE_A
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO TABLE_B(
ID,
COLUMN1,
COLUMN2)
VALUES(
:new.ID,
:new.COLUMN1,
:new.COLUMN2);
END IF;
END;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "my_trigger" ENABLE
/

 CREATE SEQUENCE   "MY_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 5002 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;


/

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "MYSEQ_SEQ_IOT" 
before insert on table_a
for each row
begin
select MY_SEQ.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "MYSEQ_SEQ_IOT" ENABLE
/
```

Now when I run this statement:

```
INSERT INTO PER_ART(
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2
    )
VALUES(
    1111111,
    2222222);
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TABLE_B"."ID")
ORA-06512: at "my_trigger", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'my_trigger'
```

Why is the ID null when the sequence should be populating it?

Comment: If the trigger is called `my_trigger` then `ALTER TRIGGER  "my_trigger" ENABLE` won't work, because `"my_trigger"` is not the same as `my_trigger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which your two triggers fire is indeterminate.  In my opinion, the best solution would be to just use one trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_A
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  select MY_SEQ.nextval
    into :new.id 
    from dual;

  INSERT INTO TABLE_B(
    ID,
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2)
  VALUES(
    :new.ID,    -- Or use MY_SEQ.curreval
    :new.COLUMN1,
    :new.COLUMN2);
END;
```

If you must have two triggers for some reason, then you can control their firing order using the FOLLOWS and PRECEDES clauses of the CREATE TRIGGER statement.  Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-2585112C-C48F-40ED-B825-21DF975EA126) for details on controlling trigger order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't know this. To confirm then it would be FOR EACH ROW FOLLOWS MYSEQ_SEQ_IOT? I have tried it and it seems to work, but I just want to confirm this is not a coincidence and the right approach!

Comment: If it works, then it's probably correct.  I have not actually used the FOLLOWS/PRECEDES clauses myself.